# How to change background color of overflow menu (popup Menu) for action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am using android compact library for building the action bar for both older and newer versions of android. so my requirement includes that i need to show action bar in blue color. now i have changed the action bar background color to blue , now i want to change the background color of popup menu  which comes when we click on overflow icon. I tried in many ways but nothing is changing the background color.any one suggest me whether we can change the background color of popup menu using app-compact library or not, if we can please suggest me

Comment: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: @VenuRao This will work only if we are using sherlock library

Comment: select theme for App Compact Light..i think u are using v7 compact lib

Comment: not working @Venu Rao

Comment: Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095733/toolbar-pop-up-theme-android

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your toolbar element

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.YourApp"
```

Then in your `styles.xml` define the popup menu style

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.YourApp" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/your_background_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Note that you need to use `colorBackground` and never `background`. The latter would be applied to everything (the menu itself and each menu item), the former applies only to the popup menu.

Source: [Style appcompat-v7 Toolbar menu background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591447/style-appcompat-v7-toolbar-menu-background/28591945#28591945)

Comment: If you want to just change the color of the overflow menu, than set android:colorBackground to whatever you want, like @stackex suggested. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:popupBackground` into styles.

like

```
<style name ="MyPopupMenu" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupMenuStyle">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No pankaj its not working. here i should use only "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" theme. because i am using appcompact library for supporting both lower and higher versions. so using that theme i have to customize

Comment: Then change `android:Theme.Holo.Light` with `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

Comment: Thanks for the help. but sorry it is changing the background of Drop down i mean action bar spinner. I need to change the background of menu which comes when we click on over flow menu icon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64390171/1638277 for appcompat / material theme v21+ solution

Comment: @avianey your solution does not work.