# How to change the background color of dropdown menu in the actionbar

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, background-color, android-menu

I'm working on an android app and I'm facing some problems in designing my actionbar. I'm using the dark actionbar with white icons on it. I have a dropdown menu popped when I click the overflow icon. Everything is good but I need light background for the dropdown menu with red colored text. I have tried editing the theme in `styles.xml` but I can only change the background color of dropdown menu when I'm using the light colored theme.

I can get the light colored dropdown menu when I change the `Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light` but other icons like **'Search'** turn very light and hardly visible (see 2nd picture). How can I change the text color on the drop down menu from black to red and make the **'Search'** icon visible.

[image]        [image]

Here is the code for more insight

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopUpMenu</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/gloryred</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopUpMenu"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**menu_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    com.example.unitedstates.app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    com.example.unitedstates.app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
    android:title="@string/action_overflow"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    com.example.unitedstates.app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_help"
            android:title="@string/action_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
            android:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_about"
            android:title="@string/action_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
            android:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_feedback"
            android:title="@string/action_feedback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_feedback"
            android:showAsAction="never"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change the background color and text color of the `dropdown menu` in the `actionbar` like this.

Set the style for the popup menu in styles.xml.

```
 <style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

         <item name="android:background">@color/YourColor</item>
         <item name="android:textColor">@Color/YourColor</item>

</style>
```

Now set this style as the `popupTheme` for your `toolbar`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"          
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

          // rest of your code
      app:popupTheme="@style/PopupMenuStyle" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution for thoses who are using Material theme with androidx.appcompat:

as of appcompat:1.2.0
you need to create a res/drawable/mtrl_popupmenu_background.xml and set it a custom color :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>

  <corners
      android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
      android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>

  <padding
      android:bottom="8dp"
      android:top="8dp"/>

</shape>
```

Then create a dedicated theme :

```
<style name="YouTheme.PopupMenuStyle">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/YouThemePopupMenu.Overflow</item>
</style>

<style name="YouThemePopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu"/>

<style name="YouThemePopupMenu.Overflow" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">?attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/mtrl_popupmenu_background</item>
</style>
```

Then use it inside your Toolbar :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/YourTheme.PopupMenuStyle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use black back ground you can to easy way go to `res > drawable-hdpi > menu_dropdown_panel_example.9.png`
 this is the nine patch image other then black lines replace its color to black or glory red if you want

as same you have to do in 
`res>drawable-mdpi>menu_dropdown_panel_example.9.png`
`res>drawable-xhdpi>menu_dropdown_panel_example.9.png`
`res>drawable-xxhdpi>menu_dropdown_panel_example.9.png`