# how can I change the background colour of my overflowmenu?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to make the background colour in my overflow menu different from that of my `toolbar`.

At present it is like this:

[image]

Before someone marks this as duplicate: I've tried so many things, suggestions from SO like:

[How to change the background color of the options menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu)

[How to change background color of overflow menu (popup Menu) for action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864142/how-to-change-background-color-of-overflow-menu-popup-menu-for-action-bar)

[How to change the background color of the overflow menu in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158160/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-overflow-menu-in-android)

but nothing is working for me. The overflowmenu is still blue. Right now my code looks like this:

**The toolbar in my activity:**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarStyle"
        android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

**My styles.xml:**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<style name="CustomToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<!-- Menu item theme here. -->
<style name="CustomPopupStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

**My colors.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <drawable name="color_one">#FF9DEFDA</drawable>
    <drawable name="color_two">#FF9DEFDA</drawable>
    <drawable name="color_three">#ffcbcbcb</drawable>
    <drawable name="color_four">#ff0000</drawable>
    <drawable name="color_five">#ff0000</drawable>
    <drawable name="color_six">#ffffffff</drawable>
    <drawable name="color_seven">#FBAE9E</drawable>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#0A7FDA</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#ece6e8</color>


    <color name="list_divider">#d9d9d9</color>
    <color name="list_row_start_color">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="list_row_end_color">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="list_row_hover_start_color">#1871EF</color>
    <color name="list_row_hover_end_color">#1871EF</color>
    <color name="color_seven">#FBAE9E</color>

</resources>
```

Any ideas how I can fix this problem? Tx.

Comment: You must use custom TextView as an Item in the menu, then you can control the colors, IMO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19659637/909317

Comment: try the solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231556/9809880

Comment: @Sunny I think that link is for actionbar only, I am using a toolbar.

Comment: If the link i provided did not work, try this link as @karakuri has explained his answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40684110/9809880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This `style` in your `Style.xml` And after set it in your `ToolBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

And in `Activity`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
```