# Toolbar options menu background color

Tags: android, menu, popup, toolbar, android-optionsmenu

I am using the toolbar for android.
I just want to change the background color of the overflow menu. But it is not changing.

Style xml

```
<style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar XML

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle" />
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To change the toolbar options menu color, add this to your toolbar element

```
app:popupTheme="@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle"
```

Then in your `styles.xml` define the popup menu style

```
<style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/mtrl_white_100</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mtrl_light_blue_900</item>
</style>
```

Note that you need to use `colorBackground` **not** `background`. The latter would be applied to everything (the menu itself and each menu item), the former applies only to the popup menu.

Comment: I think the popupTheme property only works on API 21 and up

Comment: This didn't work for me, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554996/change-toolbar-color-in-appcompat-21) did.

Comment: what if I want background with borders?

Comment: @CapitanNerd no, use support libraries... and it's `app:popupTheme`, not `android:popupTheme`

Comment: For me, `android:colorBackground` didn't work, but `android:background` did

Answer (score 11):

Edit:

if you just want a white overflow popup menu just do this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:theme="@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"" />
```

and remove the redundant popupTheme your Style xml

```
<style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
     <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

You should also include this in your top (parent) Layout

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: No, the toolbar is from the Support Library and is backwards compatible

Answer (score 11):

**Simplest way**

If you just want a white overflow popup menu just do this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Also, take a look at the value of `android:layout_height` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Option Menu]

This is how I changed the background color of the options menu for `MaterialToolbar` or `Toolbar`, I used the `popupMenuBackground` (`android:colorBackground` not work for API 21 or upper for me) attribute in a custom style and apply that style to the `popupTheme` attribute of the toolbar.

In layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle"
    app:title="@string/app_name" />
```

In `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="MenuStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="popupMenuBackground">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```