# changing overflow menu toolbar text and background color

Tags: android, toolbar

This is my toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStylepopuptheme" />
```

and my style.xml

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarStylepopuptheme" >
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffff55</item>
</style>
```

I already checked a lot on the internet, nothing seems to work for me. My app supports API level 16 and above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toolbar options menu background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095733/toolbar-options-menu-background-color)

Comment: if i changed popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStylepopuptheme" in xml to app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStylepopuptheme"  the text color changes but the background is not changing

Comment: use with 'app:' and assign parent to the style 'ToolbarStylepopuptheme' same as above style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to use :**

```
<item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
```

or, add this : `parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu"`
 and try it with your codes.

Finally:

```
<style name="ToolbarStylepopuptheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
```

And i forgot to say, my bad! add this(**app**) to your **Toolbar**:

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStylepopuptheme"
```

Comment: i am testing it on android 5.0 if that might make a difference

Comment: Jesus! :) , look at this: http://i.imgur.com/QTeruLO.png worked on `5.1.1` .and you said, `5` ? means `21 api`?

Comment: yeah i am using the normal style

Comment: Sorry i didn't see you are using **android** check my answer again please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101466/discussion-between-has19-and-linx64).