# Android custom optionMenu in toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-optionsmenu

I made an activity and implemented toolbar with options menu. How to change design from optionsmenu ??

This is how [it looks now](http://postimg.org/image/z8r2fid1h/) and [need to achieve](http://postimg.org/image/68wurnfd7/).

**MainActivity.class**

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_toolbar);
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

**menu_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:title="@string/edit_menu"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification_settings"
        android:title="@string/notification_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about_engage"
        android:title="@string/about_engage"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contact"
        android:title="@string/contact_engage"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095733/toolbar-options-menu-background-color

Comment: You mean the color or position?

Answer (score 0):

You are using light theme and it shows dark menu. Use dark theme and it will show light menu.

from styles:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

change the parent theme.