# How to change background color of option menu on android without other changing?

Tags: android, background-color, android-theme

My app's theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. To change background color of option menu, I inserted this code `<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/darkblue</item>` in style.xml. This code worked well, however, some changes that I don't want, were added. Option menu panel's corner turned into be angular from rounded. And ripple effect was gone. How can I change option menu's background color without other changing?

Comment: Here is the possible solution for [How to change the background color of the options menu for MaterialToolbar or Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76234743/14224828)

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2/20077381#20077381)
I tried this and worked

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
   parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
<!-- Popup Menu Background Color styles -->
<style name="MyPopupMenu" 
   parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/Your_color_for_background</item> 

</style>
<!-- Popup Menu Text Color styles -->
<style name="TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/Your_color_for_text</item>
</style>
```

i found a better and easier way to do it... just add this to your style and change the color:

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">#FFFF</item>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your link is so useful.